# react-router-redux - app doesnt re-render after dispatching a push-action

Tags: react-router-redux

I'm trying to integrate the newest Version of react-router & react-router-redux into sample application from a react-book. But i can't get the example working with routing over react-router-redux push/replace function.
I'm not certain if its a bug or i'm using the functions wrong.

**actions/index.js**

```
...
export function dismissVote(history) {
   // this changes the history locations an  application re-renders
  //return () => history.push('/votes');

  // this changes the history locations but application doesnt re-render
  return dispatch => dispatch(push('/votes'))
}
...
```

## Version used (package.json)

"react-router-dom": "4.1.1"
"react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6"

## App Repository (clone from github)

https://github.com/ap0yuv/voteapp.git

## How to reproduce my issue

- clone the repo.
- cd ./myapp
- npm run start:hot && npm start
- Launch Application in Browser @ localhost:3000/votes/vote_1
- Click Button "Vote later"

### Expected Behavior

Browser Location is changed to localhost:3000/votes/ 
AND
The List of all votes (localhost:3000/votes) is visible (VotePage)

### Actual Behavior

Browser Location is changed to localhost:3000/votes/ 
AND
Page of Current Vote (vote_1) is still shown

If i pass the history object to the function to route, the proper page is displayed.

More Information about the code:
src/common/containers/SingleVotePage is the entry point for /votes/vote_1
and passes dismissVote() from src/actions to